# Monitor for Hashicorp vaut fields

Tags: vault

I'm using the Hashicorp vault to store the application configuration in kv secrets. I need to perform an action based on the values getting change in the kv secrets. Is there is any way to monitor the field change or at least monitor any update to the kv secret?

Comment: This feature is [not available](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/3687) unless your application is running in kubernetes where it's possible to configure a [sidecar](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar).